# MySQL Query for Tagging System, Selecting Used Tags Only

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have a tagging system implemented in PHP and MySQL, with the following tables:

Table: blog_tags

- tag_id
- tag_name

Table: blog_tags_assoc

- tag_assoc_id
- article_id
- tag_id

Table: blog_articles

- article_id
- article_title
- article_content

I have them all linked using the Many to Many relationship 
(reference to something similar: [How to store tags in MySQL tags, one field in total or one filed for each tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819934/how-to-store-tags-in-mysql-tags-one-field-in-total-or-one-filed-for-each-tag))

What I'm trying to do now is make a MySQL query that selects all the tags from blog_tags that have actually been referenced by the articles in blog_articles.

So far, I know that "HAVING" is something I might use…but I'm not sure how?
Any ideas or suggestions would be most welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get a tag name as well as a count of articles that tag has been used.

```
SELECT
    `blog_tags`.`tag_name`,
    count(*) AS `blog_article_count`
FROM `blog_tags`
    JOIN `blog_tags_assoc`
        ON `blog_tags`.`tag_id`=`blog_tags_assoc`.`tag_id`
    JOIN `blog_articles`
        ON `blog_articles`.`article_id`=`blog_tags_assoc`.`article_id`
GROUP BY `blog_tags`.`tag_name`
```

Comment: Thanks!!  Is there a more efficient way of writing this though?  It seems a waste of resources with so many JOINs

Comment: @Jay I guess the blog_articles join is not needed. I guess I just saw all 3 tables and my mind just joined them all together. Joins are actually not bad at being efficient. Another option would be to use a subquery instead of the join to get the count, but I would think the join is better (not a dba, just from experience).

Comment: I see - I removed that last join as you suggested, and it works fantastic.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to know the tags that have been used in articles, then you can simply do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag_id, tag_name
FROM blog_tags
INNER JOIN blog_tags_assoc USING ( tag_id );
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there also a way to count the # of results per tag in this query?  How would it be retrieved in PHP?